# How do the playable characters rank in terms of weight and resistance to knockback attacks?

Tags: borderlands-2

I've read this [Reddit /r/Borderlands post, 'Is it just me, or is Krieg "heavy"?'](http://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands/comments/1irez6/is_it_just_me_or_is_krieg_heavy/) and its comments, and learned that Krieg is heavier than most (or all) of the other characters and more resistant to knockback attacks.

Quoting the related part of the post and some of the comments:

> - I [playing as Krieg] can't grenade jump as high as with the other characters.
> - ...that's just how Krieg works. His greater mass makes him largely resistant to knockback attacks, too, which is why he can go toe-to-toe with Loaders.
> - It was stated by Paul Hellquist on the GBX forums in [an Xbox support topic](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?p=4110466#post4110466) & [a PC/Mac support topic](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?p=4110468#post4110468):
>
>   > This is because we made Krieg's mass heavier than the other characters. The change was so that many of the enemies (notably the loaders) could not create situations where you could not be effective with Krieg's action skill because they would knock you back so far that you could not get a hit in on them when you closed to melee range.
>   >
>   > The unfortunate side effect is that the impulse on the geyser is not enough to get you up as far when you are playing Krieg. It was a trade well worth making since the entire character was frustrating and unfun before this change.

I would like to know: **How do the other playable characters rank in terms of weight or knockback attack resistance?** Are the rest pretty much the same, or are some characters, heavier than the others?

Comment: Sounds like something they did just to balance Krieg's ability, meaning the others probably are more or less the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To anything I could find, only Krieg has a difference. He has knock back resistance to make his ability more effective.

All of the other characters have normal mass and resistances.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Krieg has more Knockback resistance. The developers said in an interview, that they made this change so he can go toe-to-toe with loaders or other mobs that knockback in melee.
Doesn't have a very important reason, otherwise.

Answer (score -3):

If there are different weights, my guess would be below from heavies to lightest.

Krieg
Salvador
Axton
Zer0
Maya
Gaige

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stackexchange. We encourage researched, sourced answers here where possible. I'd encourage you to check your "guess" and see whether you can provide definite knowledge :-)